# Access value inside a mongo object, when you know the key but not the value

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find the value of a key inside of a mongo object. This is what my document in mongo looks like:

```
_id: 123456
▼ Item_Data: Object
   ▼ Payload: Object
      ▼ Items: Array
         ▸ 0: Object
         ▼ 1: Object
            key1: "string1"
            key2: "string2"
            key3: "string3"
         ▸ 2: Object
         ▼ 3: Object
            key1: "string4"
            key2: "string5"
            key3: "string6"
```

What I am trying to do:

1. I am given the value of a key, for example, in this case, I am given a string value "string1" for key1
2. I search the "Items" array for the object that has a key1 value of "string1". (each object has a unique key1 value)
3. I want to find the value of key2 that is in the same object I found in the previous step

So I input the "string1", find the object that has "string1" value in key1, and it outputs the value of key2 in that same object. In this case, it would output "string2"

I have tried a couple of methods (all of which didn't work) until I found this, which seemed the most promising.

```
test = myCollection.find_one({ "_id": 123456, "Item_Data.payload.items.key1" : "string1" },
    { "Item_Data.payload.items.$": 1 })
```

If I do print(test), I get:

```
{'_id': 123456, 'Item_Data': {'payload': {'items': [{'key1': 'string1', 'key2': 'string2', 'key3': 'string3'}]}}}
```

I tried to hone in on the relevant data by using

```
test = myCollection.find_one({ "_id": 123456, "Item_Data.payload.items.key1" : "string1" },
    { "Item_Data.payload.items.$": 1 })['Item_Data']['payload']['items']
```

but this just prints

```
[{'key1': 'string1', 'key2': 'string2', 'key3': 'string3'}]
```

Now this thing above ^^ is a list (I checked using type()), but when I do len(), it returns 1.

I also tried the following code:

```
var1 = json.dumps(test)
var2 = json.loads(var1)
print(type(test))
print(type(var1))
print(type(var2))
print(len(test))
print(len(var2))
```

which returns

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
1
1
```

Essentially I am getting the whole data as a single element list, and thus cannot do something like

```
print(var2['key2'])
```

to get the value of key2.

I feel like I am doing this completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "Item_Data.payload.items.key1": "string1"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Item_Data.payload.items"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Item_Data.payload.items.key1": "string1"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      key2: "$Item_Data.payload.items.key2"
    }
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 123456,
    "key2": "string2"
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EYSWZhPUJYM)

Comment: Lifesaver!!!! ❤️

Out of curiosity, how would I get and store the array if key2 stored an array instead of a string "string2"? Thanks!

Comment: instead of $ project use {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      key2: {
        $addToSet: "$Item_Data.payload.items.key2"
      }
    },
    
  }